# HibernateException- identifier of an instance of Domain was altered from X to Y

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0, spring-data-jpa

I am getting an exception when I am updating Parent record in spring data jpa.

This is my code:

**ParentEntity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CAMP")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Parent extends AbstractEntity  {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "tkeygenerator")
@GenericGenerator(name = "tkeygenerator", strategy = "com.custom.TKeyGenerator",
parameters = {@org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "sequence", value = "TKEY_SEQ")})
@Column(name = "TKEY", nullable = false)    
private String id;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "SUB_CAT_TYPE_CODE", referencedColumnName =   "SUB_CAT_TYPE_CODE")
private Child child;
@Column(name = "DATE")
@Basic
private LocalDate date;
}
```

**Child Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SUB_CAT_TYPE")
@AttributeOverrides({
@AttributeOverride(name = "code", 
                   column = @Column(name = "SUB_CAT_TYPE_CODE", length = 30)),
@AttributeOverride(name = "description", 
                   column = @Column(name = "SUB_CAT_TYPE_DESC", length = 255))})
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class Child extends AbstractTypeDesc {}
```

**TestCode**

```
public Parent update(@PathVariable("id") String id, @Valid @RequestBody  UpdateDto dto) {

      Parent parentObj = parentRepository.findById(id);
      mapper.map(dto, parentObj); // Dozer to map incoming dto to domain                  

      childRepository.findByCode(dto.child().getCode())
                     .map(child -> { 
                           parentObj.setChild(child);
                           return child;
                      });

      return parentRepository.save(parentObj); //Exception occurs here
}
```

I am getting an exception while trying to update code variable of child entity in parent entity as fk. It says `can't alter code from X to Y`.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what went wrong in above code block for update operation.Although not much clear why its happening.Dozer mapping which maps dto to Domain was causing issue it was changing the value of child entity and then again when i was trying to set child entity through setter method It was causing "Id alter exception", Though i thats the same thing i dont know why it was taking it differently. below is the working Working code.

Test code should be like

```
public Parent update(@PathVariable("id") String id, @Valid @RequestBody       UpdateDto dto) {

Parent parentObj = parentRepository.findById(id);

childRepository.findByCode(dto.child().getCode())
                 .map(child -> { 
                       parentObj.setChild(child);
                       return child;
                  });
mapper.map(dto, parentObj); // Dozer dto to domain mapping was causing problem                   

return parentRepository.save(parentObj); 
}
```